# Why is multiple independent index always better than concatenated index

Tags: index, index-tuning

[Index Merge: Combining Multiple Indexes](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/index-merge-performance)

> It is one of the most common question about indexing: is it better to
>   have one index for each column or a single index for all columns of a
>   where clause? The answer is very simple in most cases: one index with
>   multiple columns is better—that is, a concatenated or compound index.
>   “Concatenated Indexes” explains them in detail.

I can totally understand this assertion under this scenario:

```
TABLE( A,B,C )　
Indexing 1: Index A, Index B, Index C
Indexing 2: Index (A,B,C)
Query: JOIN ON X.B=B AND X.C=C
```

because under this scenario, Indexing 2 cannot used at all ( I know about the exceptions )

but under this scenario:

```
TABLE( A,B,C )　
Indexing 1: Index A, Index B, Index C
Indexing 2: Index (A,B,C)
Query: JOIN ON X.A=A X.B=B AND X.C=C
```

I think Indexing 2 is better, it only needs to traverse 1 index tree instead of 3 right ?

Comment: Highly depends on what your data and your queries look like - there's no simple, generally valid answer to this....

Comment: so the assertion in the quote isn't really valid isn't it ?

Comment: @zinking I think you misread it...

Comment: 2 Problems: 1. Traversing 3 small indices for A,B,C doesn't take much more resources than the compound index, but those indices will be much more versatile. 2. Only thinking about maximum performance for this single query is most likely wrong, memory pressure and I/O load from many special indices will limit your total system performance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Original author here.

The quote is meant as following:

In your first query, just filtering on B and C, what would be better:

```
Indexing 1: Index B, Index C
Indexing 2: Index (B,C)
```

Clearly, Indexing 2 is better.

The context was meant to be: if I index all columns, is it better to have one index with all of them, or one separate index for every column. In that case, it is almost always better to have one with all columns.

It's a design advice, not for assessment.

Comment: And don't forget to read the page quoted in the question! It includes specific information about the contents of the two columns as well. Just because a query restricts on 2 columns doesn't mean that an index on both columns is always better! If the first column is already unique or "mostly unique" then it may well be more efficient to just index the first column resulting in a much smaller index and to visit the actual table to check the values for the second column.

Comment: Not clear. Indexing strategy 2, if done everywhere, will use much more system resources which has a very likely potential to be worse than 1, but there is no general answer to this.

Comment: @JürgenStrobel Have you read the linked article? http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/index-merge-performance Sure there are exceptions, but for the majority it is clearly better.

Comment: Define the majority. For any non trivial schema with lots of tables and different queries, a big amount of data, and precious memory at the hardware limit, NO. For toy applications which fit into memory in total, yes.

Comment: Also the linked article is plainly oversimplifying and wrong. Reading one index for (A,B,C) is slower (due to size) than reading 2 indices for A and B.

Comment: @JürgenStrobel sorry, I just don't see your argument. I'm talking about two facts: (1) one index lookup if faster than two; (2) combining the result of two index lookups needs resources too.

Comment: @JürgenStrobel If you think so, prove it.